# How to reorder tensor columns in custom layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

In `numpy` I can replace columns with this code:

```
t1 = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
print(t1)

t2 = np.zeros((2,2))

t2[:,0] = t1[:,1]
t2[:,1] = t1[:,0]

print(t2)
```

How to implement similarly code in custom layer of Tensorflow with tensors? I tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        m = tf.Variable(lambda: inputs)
        
        m[:,0] = inputs[:,1]
        m[:,1] = inputs[:,0] # TypeError: 'ResourceVariable' object does not support item assignment
        
        #indices = tf.constant([[0,1],[1,1]])
        #updates = tf.constant([inputs[0,0], inputs[1,0]])
        #m.scatter_nd_update(indices, updates) # TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
        
        return m
```

Then I try to create model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


input_1 = Input(shape=(2, 2), name='inp')
output = CustomLayer()(input_1)
model = Model(input_1, output)
```

Model not created with errors. I tried to apply two approaches: like numpy slicing and scatter_nd_update. I use Tensorflow 2.0, Eager Execution and tf.keras.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your implementation (alongside your bug), the biggest is that if you want to use graph mode for faster computations, the line of code `m = tf.Variable(lambda: inputs)` will be a problem since you cannot create Variables in graph mode.

I propose two methods to swap two columns:

- using tf.concat
- using tf.gather

```
import tensorflow as tf


class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        
        # first method
        """
        c1 = inputs[:,0:1]
        c2 = inputs[:,1:2]
        
        return tf.concat([c2, c1], axis=1)
        """
        # second method
        return tf.gather(inputs, indices = [1,0], axis=1)

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


input_1 = Input(shape=(2, 2), name='inp')
output = CustomLayer()(input_1)
model = Model(input_1, output)
```